# Get ServiceProvider inside AddOpenIdConnect without BuildServiceProvider()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there a good way to get the `ServiceProvider` in the `AddOpenIdConnect`, **or** configure the ClientSecret later where we have the DI container fully setup? (e.g. in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)`)

We're getting the client secret from somewhere else and we like to use DI for that.

Currently we do this, but I really like to remove  `services.BuildServiceProvider()`

```cs
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOpenIdConnect(AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(); // we like to prevent this
        options.ClientSecret = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISecretRetriever>().GetClientSecret();
```

#### Notes

For events like `OnValidatePrincipal` we could get it from `CookieValidatePrincipalContext.HttpContext.RequestServices`

Using `services.BuildServiceProvider()` will give this warning:

> warning "Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in a additional copy of Singleton services being created"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration system for authentication uses the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1). This means that the following approach would have a *similar* effect to the approach shown in your question:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        // ...
    });

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
});
```

This is useful because the options pattern [supports DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-di-services-to-configure-options), using something like the following:

```
services.AddOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AuthenticationScheme)
    .Configure<ISecretRetriever>((options, secretRetriever) =>
    {
        options.ClientSecret = secretRetriever.GetClientSecret();
    });
```

To get access to the `Configure` method that works with DI, you must first call `AddOptions`. In this example, `Configure` is given a single type argument, which represents the dependency that's needed. This is passed into your configuration callback as the second parameter, after the `OpenIdConnectOptions` instance that's being configured.

Answer (score 0):

To build off of Kirk's answer for a fuller example

```
// Register our custom options -- we can resolve this as IOptions<MyCustomOptions>
services.Configure<MyCustomOptions>(config.GetSection(optionsSection));

// Configure OIDC
var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(schemeName, options => ...);

// Update OIDC config with our custom options
authBuilder.Services.AddOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>(schemeName)
    .Configure<IOptions<MyCustomOptions>>((oidcOptions, myOptions) =>
    {
        oidcOptions.ClientSecret = myOptions.Value.SecretTime;
    });

// register some other services
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Foo>(sp => {
    var myOpts = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MyCustomOptions>>();
    new Foo(myOpts.Value.SecretTime)
};
```